# how do you check the directory in dfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have created a directory in dfs called /foodir to test, as below:

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir /foodir
```

Can someone tell me where is this /foodir saved? How can I check the path? I need to make sure, it is not saved under localfile system /tmp because, everytime server is rebooted /tmp is deleted.

Any ideas how to check the /foodir path in the server file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends how you setup your core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files...

If `fs.defaultFS` is not set to a `file://` path (the default), then your local /tmp is not touched

If your datanode and namenode data directories are not set to your local /tmp (also the default), then nothing is stored there either

You can explicitly make a HDFS path via

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://namenode.fqdn:port/foodir
```

Otherwise, just run `ls /tmp` and check if there's files there you made